# Checking if difference between two dates in greater than a year - Java

Tags: java, android, date

I have a date, and I want to see if that date is further/less than 1 year away from today. For example, the the date is 13th May 2017, it would return true, if it was 13th May 2018, it would return false.

The bug at the moment in my code is that it would return true for December 2014 (which should return false).

Any ideas?

```
private boolean checkIfDateIsInRange() {
        Calendar today = DateTimeHelper.dateToCalendar(new Date());
        if (currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) > today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1 || currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) < today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The dateToCalendar method is as follows:

```
public static Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [Joda Times](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and you can find [Years Between](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Years.html#yearsBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)

```
public static Years yearsBetween(ReadableInstant start,
                                 ReadableInstant end)
```

Comment: Joda time is too bloated for the functions we need, but thanks.

Comment: It's a pretty heavy, but complete and mature solution. Working with dates with custom code can be frustrating. There are numerous little things which can break the final result in your custom code.

Comment: @spogebob92 then i Think Sir Titus gave nice solution,try with that

Comment: @spogebob92 If I understand the word *bloated*, then the `Calendar` class was bloated, way too many responsibilities in one single class. Joda-Time is not. Another thing is: Joda-Time has been replaced with java.time, the modern Java date and time API. See the answers [by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449221/5772882) and [by klabe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73889564/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> see if that date is further/less than 1 year away from today

Use `LocalDate.isAfter` for comparison.

```
LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ).isAfter(
    LocalDate.now().plusYears( 1 )  // Better to pass an explicit time zone than rely on the JVM’s current default: LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( “Pacific/Auckland” ) )
)
```

## Details

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android see the back-port project, *ThreeTenABP*.

Determine today’s date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, today in Paris France early morning is still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
```

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time of day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Calculate a year into future.

```
LocalDate yearFromToday = today.plusYears( 1 ) ;
```

Instantiate your date.

```
LocalDate x = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Compare.

```
Boolean isOverYearInFuture = x.isAfter( yearFromToday ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

`startDate.plusYears(1).isBefore(endDate);`

I find the code pretty self explanatory. Rather than measuring the difference between the two dates, adding a year to the first date and comparing is simpler. The code works if `startDate` and `endDate` have type `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays((long)Math.abs(today.getTimeInMillis() - currentDate.getTimeInMillis())) >= 365){
    // Is one or more years after or before.
}
```

If you want to account for leap years, you can do this:

```
final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
public boolean moreTheOneYearDifference(Calendar c1, Calendar c2){
    int days = 365;
    if (c1.before(c2) && gc.isLeapYear(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
        days += 1;
    } else if (gc.isLeapYear(c2.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
        days += 1;
    }
    return TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toDays((long)Math.abs(c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis())) >= days
}
```

Comment: this is a better solution IMO

Comment: Would not work with leap years. It is easier to get the date of today and add one year with `Calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle you're right, I haven't considered that.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle yeah that is the downside

Comment: The issue with this solution is that (using today as example), it will only return true up to May 2015/May 2017, when I require January 2015/June 2017 to return true as well (if that makes sense).

Comment: @spogebob92 It should return `true` for all the dates that you've mentioned because I've used `>=` (more then or equal to 365 days).

Comment: might be a bit pedantic, but don't forget that there are also leap seconds (last one added in 2015)

Comment: The code is both flawed and confusing. Your way of counting days assumes there are always 24 hours in a day, which is not the case because of summer time (DST) and other time anomalies. Your logic for determining whether you should count 365 or 366 days because of a leap year is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is only checking if the year part of the dates has a greater difference then 1, which of course will produce incorrect results for values like 2015-1-1 and 2016-12-31.

I would recomment adding a year to the lower of the two dates (after cloning it ofc.) and then checking if it is still before the later date, in which case the difference is more than a year.

```
public static boolean isMoreThanAYearDifference(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
    final Calendar earlierDate;
    final Calendar laterDate;
    if(c1.before(c2)) {
        earlierDate = (Calendar) c1.clone();
        laterDate = c2;
    } else {
        earlierDate = (Calendar) c2.clone();
        laterDate = c1;
    }

    earlierDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    return earlierDate.before(laterDate);
}
```

Comment: no need to clone the 2nd one, you only modify `earlierDate`.

Comment: Yeah, after a dozen times hunting bugs that were the result of not cloning  calendar objects before modifying them I made it a habbit to allways clone all calendar objects passed to the function. ;-) But you're right of course...i changed it so that only earlierDate gets set to a cloned object.

Answer (score 0):

Given `today` is a Calendar of the actual date and `dateInQuestion` is a Calendar of the date to be checked:

```
Calendar oneYearPlus  = (today.clone()).add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
Calendar oneYearAgo   = (today.clone()).add(Calendar.YEAR,-1);
return oneYearPlus.after(dateInQuestion) || oneYearAgo.before(dateInQuestion);
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect syntax as after is not accessible. Will look into it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Yeah I know, just in that syntax it isn't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another way to do it:

```
public boolean checkIfInRange(Date date){

    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    Date yearBeforeToday = cal.getTime();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
    Date yearAfterToday = cal.getTime();

    return date.after(yearBeforeToday) && date.before(yearAfterToday);
}
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/SzjQEa)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need and found the official [jdk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) answer. It gives the indication to use **Period** for such kind of check on dates:

**I found the functionality so useful!**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

int numYear = 1;
//checking if the period is more than the specified number of years (last parameter)
if(checkForPeriodLimit(sdf.parse("12/04/1977"), sdf.parse("11/04/1978"), numYear)){
     System.out.println("less than"+numYear+" year ago");
} else {
    System.out.println("more than"+numYear+" year ago");
}

//period checking function
public boolean checkForPeriodLimit(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo, int periodInYear){

    Period p = Period.between(dateFrom.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
            dateTo.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());

    return ((p.getYears() < periodInYear)?true:false);
}
```

Print the result:

```
**less than 1 years ago**
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the legacy date-time classes with the modern *java.time* classes? The troublesome legacy classes were entirely supplanted by the *java.time* framework.

Comment: Right observation! It is just that I don't fall into the concurrency issues related to `java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormatter` and they become intuitive for me :). Effectively, `checkForPeriodLimit` trasform the input `Date (dateFrom and dateTo)` into `java.time.LocalDate` with the `toLocalDate()` function. To be more safe, as you suggested, the parameters `dateFrom` and `dateTo` have to be of type `LocalDate`