# using date for calender as an input to figure out the time difference

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-difference, java.util.calendar

I have the following code and trying to figure out if the date difference is greater than one year or not. If I have the two dates like this:

1. 2022-08-20 10:26:44.000
2. 2023-08-25 10:26:44.000

How should I send these two dates such that it's accepted for `moreTheOneYearDifference` method as defined below?

```
public class DateOneYearDifferenceTest {

    final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf(moreTheOneYearDifference(2022-08-20 10:26:44.000, 2023-08-25 10:26:44.000));
        

    }

    public boolean moreTheOneYearDifference(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
        int days = 365;
        if (c1.before(c2) && gc.isLeapYear(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
            days += 1;
        } else if (gc.isLeapYear(c2.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
            days += 1;
        }
        return TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toDays((long) Math.abs(c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis())) >= days;
    }

}
```

The above method was copied from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161525/checking-if-difference-between-two-dates-in-greater-than-a-year-java) post answer

Comment: You should be using `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date` or `Calendar`.  `LocalDateTime` has a parse method to convert a `String` to a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `s1 = s1.replace(" ", "T");s2 = s2.replace(" ", "T");boolean moreThanOneYearDifference = LocalDateTime.parse(s1).isBefore(LocalDateTime.parse(s2).minusYears(1L));`

Comment: Exactly how do you define a year? Usually we ignore the Leap Day, as its purpose is to slow the calendar so we can pretend a year neatly divides into whole days. So a year from August 20 is always August 20, regardless of Leap Year — at least by usual convention. In other words, we try to ignore the existence of Leap Day when counting years. You seem to have a different definition, so you should explain your definition clearly and specifically.

Comment: As @GilbertLeBlanc said, don’t use `Calendar`. It’s long outdated and was always cumbersome to work with. From the question where you copied your code instead look at [the good answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449221/5772882) and [the one by 
klabe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73889564/5772882).

Comment: The code you took from that answer is even confusing and flawed. Do your self a favour, throw it away now (I already directed you to where you can find something better).

Comment: @BasilBourque It looks to me like the code the OP copied from that other answer exactly tries to *compensate* for leap years so that the time from August 20 to August 20 is always exactly a year. However the code fails to do so correctly. And in addition it also doesn’t always count days correctly.

Comment: Tan, are you after the unsigned difference or absolute value of the difference, so without regard to which of the date-times is earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I send these two dates such that it's accepted for moreTheOneYearDifference method as defined below?

You can send like this:

```java
Calendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2022, 7, 20, 10, 26, 44); // Note: Month is 0-based
Calendar date2 = new GregorianCalendar(2023, 7, 25, 10, 26, 44); // Note: Month is 0-based
```

I corrected the month values to be 0-based (January is 0, February is 1, and so on), and created instances of `Calendar` for `date1` and `date2` using the `GregorianCalendar` class and provided the correct year, month, day, hour, minute, and second values.

**Note**: I think that you mean *moreThanOneYearDifference* and no *moreTheOneYearDifference*

> how would I go about converting 2022-08-20 10:26:44.000 such that it fits this format Calendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2022, 7, 20, 10, 26, 44) ?

You can do this way:

```java
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
c1.setTimeInMillis(format.parse("2022-08-20 10:26:44.000").getTime());

Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
c2.setTimeInMillis(format.parse("2023-08-25 10:26:44.000").getTime());
```

**But**, like [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) said: "*These terrible date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.*"

So, I recommend that you use the *modern java.time classes* if it is possible. It will be something like this:

```java
public class DateOneYearDifferenceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Original Strings
        String dateString1 = "2022-08-20 10:26:44.000";
        String dateString2 = "2023-08-20 10:26:44.000";

        // Format parser
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        // Convertion
        LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);
        LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, formatter);

        if (moreThanOneYearDifference(dateTime1, dateTime2)) {
            System.out.println("The time difference is more than one year.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The time difference is not more than one year.");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Modern method
     */
    public static boolean moreThanOneYearDifference(LocalDateTime dateTime1, LocalDateTime dateTime2) {
        long daysDifference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateTime1, dateTime2);
        return Math.abs(daysDifference) > 365;
    }
}
```

I don't know how much specific you need to be, so maybe you should edit it to consider hours, minutes, seconds, etc...

Comment: how would I go about converting `2022-08-20 10:26:44.000` such that it fits this format `Calendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2022, 7, 20, 10, 26, 44)` ?

Comment: So do I need to  retrieve year, month, date etc from my original date and put it in this format `GregorianCalendar(2022, 7, 20, 10, 26, 44)` ? I guess I'm not following you

Comment: I improved my answer, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I needed to only figure out if two dates are more than a year or not and your code does that.

Comment: One question, if the ` String dateString1 = "2022-08-20 10:26:44.000";` are not a string for me as I'm getting it from the database with datetime column, I don't need to do the string conversion like this `LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);`, right?

Comment: What the type of the object that comes from the database? I mean the Java class.

Comment: It's like this `Date beginDate = ch.getDate(Client.CHECKLIST).beginDate;` so `beginDate` is of the form `2023-08-20 10:26:44.000` if I System.out.println it.

Comment: You can do `LocalDateTime localDateTime = beginDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: Ok, thanks. And similarly I will do for current date as well since I would need to match both the dates format for comparision.

Comment: The line you suggested `LocalDateTime localDateTime = beginDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();` seems to be giving me this error : `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.sql/java.sql.Date.toInstant(Date.java:316)` Is everything okay with the conversion you suggested?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Sorry about not providing enough info. Would there be any fix for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255060/discussion-between-diego-borba-and-tan).

Comment: You should not use either of the `Date` classes for getting a `datetime` from your database. Use `LocalDateTime` for that too. Since JDBC 4.2 assuming a JDBC `ResultSet rs` use `rs.getObject("your_datetime_column", LocalDateTime.class)`. And save any and all conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, you could calculate the `Period.between(…)` two `LocalDate`s, which are part of a `LocalDateTime`, available by `LocalDateTime.toLocalDate()`.

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example datetimes
    String a = "2022-08-20 10:26:44.000";
    String b = "2023-08-25 10:26:44.000";
    // prepare a formatter that is able to parse those Strings
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    // then actually parsen them
    LocalDateTime ldtA = LocalDateTime.parse(a, dtf);
    LocalDateTime ldtB = LocalDateTime.parse(b, dtf);
    // caclulate the period between those two dates
    Period period = Period.between(ldtA.toLocalDate(), ldtB.toLocalDate());
    // check if the resulting period is a full year or more
    if (period.getYears() >= 1) {
        System.out.println("Difference is greater than or equals one year");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Difference is less than one year");
    }
}
```

Resulting output:

```
Difference is greater than or equals one year
```

Have a look at the other methods of a `Period` and if you want to involve time of day or calulate with that exclusively, check out a `Duration`:

[The Java™ Tutorials — Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Comment: Maybe not ideal, but seems to me to be the best suggestion so far. The OP may not want to throw the time of day away (from August 25 15:00 to August 25 next year 09:00, is that less than one year?) And the OP may want to know whether the difference is *strictly* more than a year. Getting this out of a `Period` is a bit more complicated. But only the OP can tell (I frankly find the question unclear). In any case a nice demonstration of java.time and some of its strong points.

Comment: Totally agree @OleV.V., I just felt like providing an alternative, even if it is not the perfect solution. There is no perfect solution to an unclear question. One would likely have to write a custom class for this, maybe using `Period` and `Duration`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. What part of question is unclear?

Comment: What’s unclear: Is the second date-time always later than the first? Do you mean *strictly* greater than a year (as opposed to equal to or less than a year)? By *one year* do you mean for example from 2022-08-20 10:26:44.000 to 2023-08-20 10:26:44.000? I believe much of the confusion comes from the code you found being flawed, which leaves doubt about what exactly you want to obtain from it.

Comment: Hi! It is not clear to me what to do if the plain *date difference* of your two dates plus times is exactly one year, zero months and zero days. Should the method `return false` or should it compare the time part down to milliseconds? "One year and one millisecond" can certainly be described as "more than one year".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    
Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(), c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
c1.setTimeInMillis(format.parse("2022-08-20 10:26:44.000").getTime());
c2.setTimeInMillis(format.parse("2023-08-25 10:26:44.000").getTime());
System.out.println(moreTheOneYearDifference(c1, c2));
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque Is there a better way to achieve with java.time package?

Comment: @Gabriel - You approach works in calling the method but that method has some issues I guess as it is not returning me correct # of days

Comment: @Tan Yes, much better and at the same time much simpler. `LocalDateTime.parse("2022-08-20T10:26:44.000").plusYears(1).isBefore(LocalDateTime.parse("2023-08-25T10:26:44.000"))`. I have replaced the spaces in the strings with `T` to conform with ISO 8601. If you don’t want this, use a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing. Search for the details, it’s straightforward enough.

Comment: Spelled out in [the smart comment by g00se under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979636/using-date-for-calender-as-an-input-to-figure-out-the-time-difference#comment135705771_76979636).